# How can I dynamically add a class to 'body' using JavaScript only for the home page?

Tags: javascript, volusion

I added this to the head, but it's not working:

```
<script>
var xpathname = (window.location.pathname);
if (xpathname ==('/')) {
$('body').addClass('home');
}
</script>
```

The site is here: http://xotdr.unxpr.servertrust.com/

Volusion doesn't allow developers to code freely so there are a lot of workarounds that I need to implement, unfortunately.

Edit: I want the class to show only on the home page `body`.

Comment: Now you removed the x, the body has a class attribute of "home" so perhaps it is the CSS that is not doing anything visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you added this to the `head` you need to execute this snippet when `body` tag is available:

```
$(function() {
    var xpathname = window.location.pathname;
    if (xpathname == '/') {
        $('body').addClass('home');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the class still isn't being added to the home page `body`.

Comment: I think the x is no longer needed

Comment: I thought that `x$` is no conflict one. Ok, if it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var bodyclass=document.createAttribute("class");
    bodyclass.value="home";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttributeNode(bodyclass);
</script>
```

Comment: I should clarify that I only want the class to show up for `body` on the home page. I forgot to include that in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
b.className += 'home';
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant only for the home page. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a old post, but the question will remain useful.

```
var xpathname = (window.location.pathname);
var ndeBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
if (xpathname ==('/')) {
    ndeBody.classList.toggle("home");
}
else{
    ndeBody.classList.toggle("home");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When I go to that URL you have syntax error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: x$ is not defined
```

e.g. you want to delete the `x` in `x$('body').addClass('home');`

Comment: I did this but the class is still not being added to the body. Just for clarity, I only want the class to show up on the home page.